# Brace-initialization vs. Parenthesis Bug

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, list-initialization

I was filing a GCC bug for this, but I'd rather double-check this.

Consider the following programs:

```
#include <utility>
template<typename T, typename A>
void F(A&& a) { T(std::forward<A>(a)); } // Note: () syntax.
int main() { int i; F<int&>(i); }
```

and:

```
#include <utility>
template<typename T, typename A>
void F(A&& a) { T{std::forward<A>(a)}; } // Note: {} syntax.
int main() { int i; F<int&>(i); }
```

Latest Clang and MSVC compilers accept both programs. GCC 5 and beyond accept the first program but reject the second, claiming `invalid cast of an rvalue expression of type 'int' to type 'int&'`.

Is this a GCC bug? Or is this indeed a difference between `T{}` and `T()` in the above context (and thus a bug in Clang and MSVC)?

**Edit:**

The issue can be narrowed down to the following simpler excerpts:

```
int i; (int&){i};
```

and

```
int i; (int&)(i);
```

Comment: Can you even define and initialize an unnamed lvalue reference? The error seems incorrect anyway.

Comment: @krzaq: I don't see why not. Also, I hit this error in a `noexcept` expression, so I'd like to understand the situation in an expression context.

Comment: This is [core issue 1288](http://wg21.link/cwg1288). GCC is supposed to be implementing its resolution, but perhaps it wasn't completely fixed.

Comment: Although `T{x}` is underspecified, see [core issue 1521](http://wg21.link/cwg1521).

Comment: @T.C.: Nice finds. Looks like answer material to me.

Comment: @T.C. Want to write an answer so I can upvote you?

Comment: @T.C. I agree with the other comments, these findings apparently settle the issue. I'll update the question to reflect them.

Comment: @Alek What would settle the issue would be GCC fixing this... so it would be good if you could check whether they already have a PR for this, and if not, please file one. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two separate issues:

- The standard is unclear what `T{x}` should do for reference type `T`. Currently [[expr.type.conv]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.type.conv#1) says that it creates a prvalue of type `T`, which is nonsense for reference types. This is [core issue 1521](http://wg21.link/cwg1521).
- The sane thing is probably to have `T{x}` for reference type `T` do roughly `T __tmp{x};` and then yield the equivalent of `static_cast<T>(__tmp)` (so xvalue for rvalue reference `T` and lvalue for lvalue reference `T`).  However, C++11 as published screwed up the specification for list-initialization of references, making it always create a temporary. The result was that `int i; int &r{i};` failed to compile because it would attempt to bind `r` to a temporary copy of `i`, which is obviously nonsense. This is fixed by [core issue 1288](http://wg21.link/cwg1288), whose resolution GCC is supposed to implement, but it looks like from the error message that it's not completely fixed.